# What Encoding does Ruby 1.9.3 use to parse the output of a shell command using backtics?

Tags: ruby, unicode, encoding

When executing

```
lines = `gpg --list-keys --with-colons horst`
```

What Encoding will the string `lines` have? How do I change how Ruby interprets it?

Background:
I have some Umlauts in some gpg keys, and I get this error when trying to split by newline:

```
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

My current workaround is this:

```
lines.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1')
```

However, I don't get why this should be `ISO-8859-1`, as my locale is `en_US.UTF-8`..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need an answer on this or not but it looks like you'll have to use the  `--display-charset` or `–charset` option in your gpg command in order to set the name of the native character set. This is used to convert some strings to proper UTF-8 encoding. You shouldn't have to enforce encoding downstream after you've done that.

Check the gpg man page on your server to see which option is available to you.